# Perl backticks when using pipes

Tags: perl, sh, backticks

I'm experiencing some problems trying to capture the output of a simple command:

```
$timeTotal = `echo $timeTotal + $time | bc -l`;
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
sh: +: not found
sh: Syntax error: "|" unexpected
```

This command works perfectly in bash but it seems sh is being actually used. At the very beginning I thought that the problem is the pipe usage (although the sum is not well interpreted neither). What confuses me is that the following command in the same script causes no error and works properly:

```
my $time = `cat $out.$step | bc -l`;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're aware that Perl can do addition, right?

Comment: Slightly off topic: Why on earth are you using a shell command to do (very) simple math? `$timetotal += $time` is the perl code you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$timeTotal` contains a trailing newline it shouldn't, so you're executing

```
echo XXX
```

and

```
+ YYY | bc -l
```

instead of

```
echo XXX + YYY | bc -l
```

You're surely missing a `chomp` somewhere.

There's also a double-quote in your command that's out of place.

Answer (score -4):

The backticks are deprecated. Use the `qx(..)` syntax instead.

```
$timeTotal = qx(echo $timeTotal + $time | bc -l");
```

Comment: Backticks are deprecated? Do you have a source for that?

Comment: No mentioned of them being deprecated in the [latest documentation](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/56e2d9fbd5fb964af1b71d8a8546c889702991ea:/pod/perlop.pod#l2136). And this doesn't answer the question at all.